# Timber Gutenberg Block - dynamic callback function

Tags: php, wordpress, twig, timber, wordpress-gutenberg

I got this in my **functions.php** where for each new block, I am currently adding another separate function of these.

I'm not quite sure how I can make this dynamic, so I only have one function.

*functions.php*

```
    function my_acf_block_render_callback( $block ) {
    $context = Timber::get_context();

    // Store block values.
    $context['block'] = $block;

    // Store field values.
    $context['fields'] = get_fields(); 

    // Render the block.
    Timber::render( 'block/bulma-card-block.twig', $context );
}
```

I got these files which i registered as a block:

bulma-card-block.twig

bulma-tag-block.twig

bulma-other-block.twig

...

Comment: Change `'block/bulma-card-block.twig'` to a variable?

Comment: @DarkBee I was assuming. The issue for me is, that I don't get how it gets called. So I am not sure how to pass a variable to use in the function. If i do:   
`'render_callback' => 'my_acf_tag_block_render_callback("bulma-card")',`
To my knowledge that will not work.

Comment: I also tried getting the name from the block, but it doesn't seem to work. That would have been the simplest solution.

Comment: How are you calling the function now then?

Comment: I am just doing this `'render_callback' => 'my_acf_tag_block_render_callback',`

Comment: I'm not seeing any way to pass arguments to the callback function. What about create one general callback and then one callback per template? e.g. `function bulma_cardcallback($block) { my_acf_block_render_callback('bulma-card-block.twig', $block); }`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [blog post](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/blog/acf-5-8-introducing-acf-blocks-for-gutenberg/) that describes the ACF blocks feature, the `$block` variable contains the name of the block under the `name` key.

This means that you could take that name to select the Twig template you want to render dynamically:

```
function my_acf_block_render_callback( $block ) {
    $slug = str_replace( 'acf/', '', $block['name'] );

    $context = Timber::get_context();

    // Store block values.
    $context['block'] = $block;

    // Store field values.
    $context['fields'] = get_fields(); 

    // Render the block.
    Timber::render(
        'block/bulma-' . $slug . '-block.twig',
        $context
    );
}
```

Comment: I noticed that we have to filter it. Because this returns `acf/bulma-card-block
`. So like in the ACF Documentation on Gutenberg Blocks I did `$slug = str_replace('acf/', '', $block['name']);` which finally works.
(Please include in your solution)
Using `label` would have been another solutions. But I didn't test.

Comment: I’m glad it worked! And you’re right! I just updated my answer.

Comment: I just noticed that this is only the case because I am using ACF. Not sure what the return value would be, if I was doing it plain old PHP style, without ACF.